# Adding html to a list item in an unordered list after it has been added to another list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an unordered list like so:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>
```

Occasionally, I'm going to drag list items from sortable1 into this sortable2, modifying it like this:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">First</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Second</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Third</li>
</ul>
```

My question is how can I append the following html inside these list items once dragged into the sortable2:

```
<a title='delete' class="itemDelete"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

I would like to use jquery, so far I have tried to append and add stuff on the dom tree of the UL changing but it goes awfully wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: create a fiddle pls

Comment: Pseudocode for js, jquery: If sortable2 changes, check if li has our html, if it does do nothing, if it doesnt append our html.

Comment: You know about sortable's [receive event](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases it helps if you make available a running example of your issue.
I'm guessing you are using jQuery UI and jQuery Sortable.

You can use the Sortable "receive" event and append your HTML to the changed element.

```js
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).append('<a title="delete" class="itemDelete"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Also jQuery UI has extensive documentation on both [Sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) and [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/), make sure you check the events section for more information that will help you.

Comment: Hey this worked! thanks so much, now when i drag back into sortable1, the intended effect appears twice. Any way i can stop that?

Comment: Yes, as you said in your pseudocode above, "check if li has our html, if it does do nothing".